# data point on an exponential line in excel

Tags: regression-analysis

I plotted a trend line in excel. The formula is y = 41899e1E-07x. What I need is to know what the points are on the trend line. I cannot figure out how to use this formula. I don't know what the e and the E mean.  Ideally, I want to show the labels on the trend line like you are able to do for the give data points. When I click on the line I do not get an option to show the value of the line at that point. I think that I need to calculate each point on the trend line but I don't know how to use that formula.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 1E-07x is at the superscript. Then you should read

$$y=41899\cdot \exp(10^{-7}x)$$

So $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm ($2.718...)$, and E is the power of $10$ in the scientific notation:

$$1.23\text{E}-7=1.23\cdot10^{-7}$$